# Convert char* to abitrary numeric type without using stringstream

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I'd like to be able to convert a char* to an arbitrary numeric type T
Similar to below, but without using the stringstream library, and obviously
that one uses the string type which I don't want to use either.

How would I go about doing this?

e.g.

```
template<class T>
T string_as_T( const string& s )
{
    // Convert from a string to a T
    // Type T must support >> operator
    T t;
    std::istringstream ist(s);
    ist >> t;
    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traits?

```
 template<class T>
 char* fmt(T value) { throw new /*some exception, or return null*/; }

 char* fmt<int>(int value) { return "%d"; } // forgive rusty specialization syntax
 // write fmt<double>, char, float, long, etc

 template<class T>
 T string_as_T( const char* s )
 {
     T val;
     sscanf(s, fmt(val), &val);
     return val;
 }
```

Comment: Nice.  I actually worked it out similar to this.  I also use sscanf.

Comment: Ok, I've modified my code to extend it using the clever fmt.  Can't seem to get that to compile though.  The error from gcc is "too few template parameter lists".  What does that mean?

Comment: Ok, sorted.  I needed to put template<> before the specialization and make it inline

Answer (score 1):

You can use [boost.conversion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/conversion/index.html), lexical_cast to achieve this.

```
#include "boost/lexical_cast.hpp"  

char* string = "15";
int output = 0;
output = boost::lexical_cast<INT_TYPE>(string);
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry but can't use boost in this project.